# How to solve infinite square root of 1+ itself or: $\varphi=\sqrt{1+\varphi}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find $\varphi$ for $\varphi=\sqrt{1+\varphi}$ or $\varphi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+...}}}}}$?

Comment: Hint: square both sides.

Comment: $$ \varphi^2 = \varphi + 1 $$
$$ 2 \varphi d \varphi = d \varphi $$ 
$$ \varphi = \frac{1}{2} $$
But I think thats wrong

Comment: @Leo What did you do there? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: implicitly differentiating, did i get that wrong too? :)

Comment: Hint: this is not really a calculus problem.

Comment: Hmm your comments make me believe im not seeing something that should be very obvious

Comment: How would you solve for $x$ in $x^2=x+1$?

Comment: $$\varphi^2-\varphi-1=0=(\varphi-a)(\varphi+b)$$

Comment: One of the solution is [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)..

Comment: @inceptio I'm sure he knows that considering he used $\varphi$...

Comment: Ha my professor even used $\varphi$ as a hint it seems. Inceptio how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @Leo Factoring it like that does not really work here, but you are right about bringing it all to the left hand side. Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Googling it now, thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the *quadratic formula*?

Comment: ooh now that I see the quadratic formula Im having a high school flashback

Comment: @Leo: One of the solution to quadratic $x^2-x-1=0$ is a golden ratio and the other is a conjugate of it. Here $\varphi= \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks guys, got it now. I feel silly :)

Comment: Shouldnt differentiating and then solving have worked too though?

On stackexchange etiquette; should I throw this question away, can I post one of your answers as an answer myself or should I take MaMings answer as the answer?

Comment: @Leo : Suppose your method worker. $\forall a \in \Bbb R$, if you solved for $\varphi^2=\varphi+ a$, you'd get the same answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commentators have already give hint how to get the possible value of $\varphi=\varphi_\infty$, it remains to show it converges.

Let $\varphi_n=\underbrace{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dots}}}}_{n}$. Then it is clear that $\varphi_n>\varphi_{n-1}$, and $\varphi_\infty>\varphi_n$ provided $\varphi_\infty>\varphi_{n-1}$. So $\varphi_n$ converges.

Comment: So after I show that it converges I reduce it to a polynomial and solve it using the quadratic equation. Ok